# How do I remove the first character of a string and treat the remaining values as an integer in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I currently am working with a large data set that was pre-populated in BigQuery. I have a column of orderID's which have the following set-up: o377412876, o380940924, etc. This is stored in a string. I need to do the following and am running into problems:

1) Strip off the first character using the BigQuery query language
2) Convert the remaining (or treat the remaining values), as an integer.

I will then run a join against the values. Now, I would be abundantly happier down this operation in either Python, R, or another language. That said, the challenge I have been given based on client needs is to write all the scripts in BigQuery's querying language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 10 * INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '^.', ''))
FROM 
  (SELECT 'o1234' AS x)

12340
```

Comment: One other thing to note is that if you're using this value in a join key, you'll need to wrap it in a subquery (e.g. `select ... from (select INTEGER(REGEXP_REPLACE(...)) as key FROM ...) as t1 JOIN ... as t2 ON t1.key = t2.key`

Comment: Great. Thanks! I will give this a try and keep you posted on the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUBSTR` function and `SAFE_CAST` (in case there are NULL values in your column). `INTEGER` does not work on BQ.

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(SUBSTR(x, 2) AS INT64)
FROM (SELECT 'o1234' AS x)
```

Output: 1234