# Error with a BigQuery regular expression

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-bigquery

This question builds off a previous question that I asked:

[How do I remove the first character of a string and treat the remaining values as an integer in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157135/how-do-i-remove-the-first-character-of-a-string-and-treat-the-remaining-values-a/20158199?noredirect=1#20158199)

I am having trouble getting a regular expression that I need for some client work to function. Basically, I want to look through all the cells in a column which has the following types of entries:

customer-o400744190

o400748216

o455239157-new-customer

other similar types with o4552334214 somewhere in the cell

and use something like REGEX_EXTRACT() to parse out or extract "oXXXXXXXXX" from every cell & dump those values into a new column. The data in the column I am pulling from is stored in a string, and can stay that way. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I worked around the problem by just using:

`RIGHT(hits_transaction_transactionId, 10)`

but know that I am only getting some of the cases that apply. Thus, this is not an acceptable long term solution. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your data universe is, you could go with /o[0-9]+/

so you would be extracting any ocurrences of o and then at least one number

Comment: If your codes are always nine digits after the o, you can make it more fail-safe by doing o[0-9]{9}